# Simple lua_yield in C not resuming correctly from Lua

Tags: c, lua, coroutine

I'm just starting to delve into lua coroutines with C and I'm having a problem with what I think should be the simplest example I can come up with.

The C:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int lua_test_yield(lua_State *L) {
        printf("1\n");
        lua_yield(L, 0);
        printf("2\n");
        lua_yield(L, 0);
        printf("3\n");
        lua_yield(L, 0);
        printf("4\n");
        lua_yield(L, 0);
        printf("5\n");
        lua_yield(L, 0);
        return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib[] = {
        {"test_yield", lua_test_yield},

        {NULL, NULL}
        };

// Used when the .so library is loaded from lua
int luaopen_mytest(lua_State *L) {
        luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
        return 1;
}
```

The Lua

```
mytest = require 'mytest'

print("Loaded")
mytest_yeild = coroutine.create(function ()
        mytest.test_yield()
end)

for i=1,5 do
        print(coroutine.resume(mytest_yeild))
end
```

The result:

```
$ lua test.lua 
Loaded
1
true
true
false   cannot resume dead coroutine
false   cannot resume dead coroutine
false   cannot resume dead coroutine
```

I find this really weird. Why does it report a successful resume twice but not print anything and then report a failed resume? What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lua_yield` is a C function, and C *does not* have a mechanism to magically jump back into a function that has halted. `lua_yield` uses the C standard library `longjmp` function to arbitrarily jump *out of* the function that called it. But it can't come back.

So what happens is that your C function yields, exiting the function and returning control to the Lua code that called `coroutine.resume`. The resume was successful, so `true` is printed. You then resume the coroutine again, which begins execution at the site *in Lua code* that called the C function that yielded. That code then exits the coroutine normally. Since the resume was also successful, `true` is printed again.

But the coroutine is now exhausted and therefore cannot be resumed.

C functions don't have a clean way to be "resumed". Indeed, the [Lua 5.1 documentation explicitly states](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_yield):

> This function should only be called as the return expression of a C function, as follows:
>
> ```
> return lua_yield (L, nresults);
> ```

Lua 5.2 and above have some ability to resume a C function, but only [through a continuation API](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.7). You cannot write a single C function that works the way a Lua yielding function works.

Answer (score 3):

To return to C code after yielding, you need to use `lua_yieldk` and have it pick up in a separate C function, like this:

```c
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int lua_test_yield_6(lua_State *L, int status, lua_KContext ctx) {
        return 0;
}

static int lua_test_yield_5(lua_State *L, int status, lua_KContext ctx) {
        printf("5\n");
        return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, lua_test_yield_6);
}

static int lua_test_yield_4(lua_State *L, int status, lua_KContext ctx) {
        printf("4\n");
        return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, lua_test_yield_5);
}

static int lua_test_yield_3(lua_State *L, int status, lua_KContext ctx) {
        printf("3\n");
        return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, lua_test_yield_4);
}

static int lua_test_yield_2(lua_State *L, int status, lua_KContext ctx) {
        printf("2\n");
        return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, lua_test_yield_3);
}

static int lua_test_yield_1(lua_State *L) {
        printf("1\n");
        return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, lua_test_yield_2);
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib[] = {
        {"test_yield", lua_test_yield_1},

        {NULL, NULL}
        };

// Used when the .so library is loaded from lua
int luaopen_mytest(lua_State *L) {
        luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, the internet needs more simple examples like this for learning.