# simple Lua corotine test crashed at first run

Tags: c++, lua, coroutine, lua-c++-connection

In brief, the test program creates a coroutine at C++ side, launch it with a Lua-side function and resume several times with some logs. It suddenly crashed at the first call to `resume` that starts coroutine running, with violated access to invalid heap memory (`0xfdfdfd`).

This is the whole code:

```
#include <juce_core/juce_core.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int debug_log( lua_State* lua )
{
    int narg = lua_gettop( lua );
    juce::StringArray tokens;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= narg; i++ )
        tokens.add( lua_tostring( lua, i ) );
    juce::Logger::writeToLog( tokens.joinIntoString( "" ) );
    return 0;
}

const char* lua_code =
    "function testfunc(arg1, arg2)\n"
    "    debug_log( \"before yield: arg1 \", arg1 )\n"
    "    coroutine.yield(1)\n"
    "    debug_log( \"after yield: arg2 \", arg2 )\n"
    "    coroutine.yield(2)\n"
    "    debug_log( \"finally in testfunc\" )\n"
    "end\n";

int main()
{
    auto* lua = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs( lua );
    lua_pushcfunction( lua, debug_log );
    lua_setglobal( lua, "debug_log" );
    luaL_dostring( lua, lua_code );

    // create a new coroutine
    auto* coro = lua_newthread( lua );

    // start corotine
    int t_testfunc = lua_getglobal( coro, "testfunc" );
    if ( t_testfunc != LUA_TFUNCTION )
    {
        juce::Logger::writeToLog( "failed to get testfunc from coro: type is " + juce::String( t_testfunc ) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    lua_pushstring( coro, "arg1" );
    lua_pushnumber( coro, 123.456 );
    int n_re = 0;
    int status = lua_resume( lua, coro, 2, &n_re ); ///< die here

    // repeatedly resume until finished
    while ( true )
    {
        juce::Logger::writeToLog( "status: " + juce::String( status ) + " with " + juce::String( n_re ) + " returned values" );
        if ( n_re > 0 )
        {
            juce::Logger::writeToLog( "  returned value " + juce::String( lua_tostring( coro, 1 ) ) );
            lua_pop( coro, n_re );
        }
        if ( status == LUA_YIELD )
        {
            status = lua_resume( lua, coro, 0, &n_re );
        }
        else if ( status == LUA_OK )
        {
            juce::Logger::writeToLog( "coroutine ended" );
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            juce::Logger::writeToLog( "coroutine returned with error: " + juce::String( status ) );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
>   coro_call.exe!luaH_getshortstr(Table * t, TString * key) 行 751  C++
    coro_call.exe!luaT_gettmbyobj(lua_State * L, const TValue * o, TMS event) 行 83  C++
    coro_call.exe!luaD_tryfuncTM(lua_State * L, StackValue * func) 行 391    C++
    coro_call.exe!luaD_precall(lua_State * L, StackValue * func, int nresults) 行 559    C++
    coro_call.exe!ccall(lua_State * L, StackValue * func, int nResults, int inc) 行 575  C++
    coro_call.exe!resume(lua_State * L, void * ud) 行 731    C++
    coro_call.exe!luaD_rawrunprotected(lua_State * L, void(*)(lua_State *, void *) f, void * ud) 行 144  C++
    coro_call.exe!lua_resume(lua_State * L, lua_State * from, int nargs, int * nresults) 行 788  C++
    coro_call.exe!main() 行 44   C++
```

Is there any misunderstanding to the Lua coroutine C API?

In addition, the Lua official document gives a pretty long part on concepts of *k function* and `lua_pcallk`, but it seems I don't need them anywhere in my test code. Where should I use these stuffs?

Comment: There are typos in the `lua_code` snippet: `corotine.yield` => `coroutine.yield`. I doubt that it is the source of your crash though. BTW, it would have been a good place to use a C++11 raw string.

Comment: @prapin Fixed typo, though it is not the origin of the bug here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in the order of arguments for `lua_resume`
It should be `lua_resume(coro, lua,` instead of `lua_resume(lua, coro,`

> concepts of k function ... Where should I use these stuffs?

There is a good example on using k-functions
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961038/1847592

Comment: I inverted the argument order. Now the coroutine starts to run, but it throws at the first call to `coroutine.yield()`, inside the function `lua_yieldk` that actually implements the yield operation.

Comment: It's not a bug. The error code is 1 which means coroutine yield. I should just ignore that exception in MSVC settings.

Comment: Switching Lua coroutines does not raise any exception catchable in MSVC.  You should start a new question and describe the problem with your code.

Comment: I'm sure it's OK. If you compile Lua source code in C++ instead of C, Lua will use throw-try-catch instead of long jump.